# How to write in firebase database from another firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Who two Apps, from different projects, from different owners account, can communicate in order to write data into one anothers Firestore database ?

(For example, how uber eats app communicates with the different restaurants orders management apps)

Comment: That's when they expose api's through which multiple application's communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration between two systems happens using APIs, so following the example you just wrote, each restaurant would have it's individual system and would have an API that allows UberEats to integrate with their system of ordering, payment, etc and that would receive information back like order being prepared, ready for delivery, etc.

It's important to add that each project shouldn't have access to the other projects database directly, therefore, all processing of data would be handled by each project's code.

Comment: So in the case of Firestore i need to use REST APIs to build a method that write into the db, then call that method from another app

Comment: "I need to use REST APIs to build a method that write into the db, then call that method from another app" -> not necessarily: you could write to two different Firestore databases **from one app**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59983424/3371862