# "Wrong app reference" when loading documents from Firestore with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in a GCP project "A" that was created from a copy of another database in project "B". This was achieved with the Cloud Firestore managed export and import service from GCP.

When trying to load documents from a specific collection from the database in project "A", an error is raised:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-935f61174138> in <module>()
      1 collection_docs = db.collection("<collection>").stream()
----> 2 for doc in collection_docs:
      3   print(doc.id)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py in reference_value_to_document(reference_value, client)
    245     if document._document_path != reference_value:
    246         msg = WRONG_APP_REFERENCE.format(reference_value, client._database_string)
--> 247         raise ValueError(msg)
    248 
    249     return document

ValueError: Document 'projects/<project B>/databases/(default)/documents/<another collection>/<document>' does not correspond to the same database ('projects/<project A>/databases/(default)') as the client.
```

Note that `<another collection>` is referenced in documents from `<collection>`

**<s>Why the reference keeps pointing to the old database?</s>**

**UPDATE:**
It turns out the initial export was correct and the references properly updated, but after that, while updating other fields using a buggy Python script, the references got unnecessarily and incorrectly "updated" to the old project.

**The correct way to obtain this field would be:**

```py
db.document(<document reference>.path)
```

Still this question remains:

**Is it possible to load the documents without bringing the reference?**

Here is the Python snippet that produces the error:

```
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'projectId': <project A>,
})

db = firestore.client()

collection_docs = db.collection("<collection>").stream()
for doc in collection_docs:
  print(doc.id)
```

Comment: I posted an answer below. Can you please check if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloud Firestore managed export and import service to export all documents or just specific collections. The data exported from one Cloud Firestore database can be imported into another Cloud Firestore database across projects. The Cloud Firestore managed export and import service is available through the [gcloud command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) and the Cloud Firestore API ([REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases), [RPC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1beta1)).

Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import), explaining the same.

Key points to note when importing data:

- When you import data, the required indexes are updated using your
  database's current index definitions. An export does not contain
  index definitions.
- Imports do not assign new document IDs. Imports use the IDs captured
  at the time of the export. As a document is being imported, its ID is
  reserved to prevent ID collisions. If a document with the same ID
  already exists, the import overwrites the existing document.

Also, I would like you to go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59983424/15803365) where a community member has explained how to use a value from the Firestore DB of one primary project in order to query the Firestore DB of a secondary project using references. Try and see if you could make it work too without errors, as it is very much possible to point a document from another project in Firestore.

**UPDATE**

I reproduced your case by creating two projects A and B. In my case, Project A has a Firestore database, with all the data which I am exporting to project B. I followed this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data) for moving the data between projects and it was successfully done. Now after this, I created a service account in Project B and gave the `Owner, Service Account Token Creator permissions`. Generated a private key file and set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the JSON file that contains the service account key like this :

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/service-account-file.json"
```

After that I  wrote the below Python script which worked fine for me and it printed the document id of my Firestore database( which was exported from Project A and imported to Project B) without any errors.

firebase.py

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth,firestore
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
 'projectId': "projectB’sID",
})
db = firestore.client()
collection_docs = db.collection("collection-name").stream()
for doc in collection_docs:
 print(doc.id)
```

requirements.txt

```
firebase_admin=5.0.2
```

Comment: The database was exported using that service. This question is about the error raised while loading documents from the database, not about how to export it.

Comment: First of all, do you need to import only specific collections and load documents from those specific collections in project A? If yes, try only exporting specific collections from the original database as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data). My guess is you are exporting a different specific collection from original database, but loading documents from a completely different collection in new database. Either export all documents, or if loading specific documents during import choose to export that collection only.

Comment: Also I would like to know, a little bit more about how you are doing it. Any Cloud buckets used? Are you following any guide because we do not have an official documentation code for import/export using Python. I am following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) and [this](https://medium.com/@cbrannen/importing-data-into-firestore-using-python-dce2d6d3cd51) document.

Comment: The export was NOT accomplished with Python. It was done using the Cloud Firestore managed export and import service from GCP's console.  The problem arised when trying to load the documents using Python after the export was done. After all, the export was correct but the reference was incorrectly updated after the export by another Python script. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.